# Web Security: where to begin

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am working on a website with a hosted company, in PHP with MySQL.

I am familiar with SQL injection and XXS, and I know how to code so that these don't happen. However, I still plan to test the website for vulnerabilities.

Now, I'm sort of new to web development, and I know there is a lot to read on website security.

1. What other attacks are out there which are *typically* used on
   websites and web servers which use PHP and MySQL?
2. How do I protect against those attacks?
3. Even if my code is perfect, what do I need to look for in the hosting company's web
   server configuration which might make the web server vulnerable?

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question to be answered well here. But: see the [OWASP's set of cheat sheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets). Good stuff.

Comment: Padding oracle attacks, if you're doing any sort of decryption of user-supplied data on the server. Timing attacks. Traffic analysis of HTTPS (it leaks page/image/script sizes and load times, for one).

Comment: One of the fewest questions I both upvote and close-vote.

Comment: Don't overlook simple logic errors that let attackers just waltz right in using your own code: http://www.codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/12/web-form-security-avoiding-common-mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Things that are good to keep in mind:

Look into `PDO` for database purposes, instead of `mysql` or `mysqli`.
(PDO is a wrapper which simplifies differences between different kinds of databases -- but also simplifies security a lot).

PDO's prepared statements both make building queries 100x easier, ***AND*** make them pretty much SQL-injection-proof, as long as you're always preparing the statements (which is stupid-easy with PDO as well).

It's seriously worth the 15 minutes to learn how to use PDO over either of the other two mysql options.

While that might net you safety from compromising your database, it doesn't protect you from data that you might store in the database to give to users, later.

In that regard:

1. validate everything that you get from users -- everything from form-inputs to GET/POST values
2. escape everything you write to a user's page as html
3. never take user-input as-is, to select classes, et cetera (ex: `include $_GET["page"];`)

JavaScript -- my baby:

1. Learn about closures and module/namespacing patterns.
2. Use them for EVERY large application that you write (especially any that require any user-information being collected, et cetera)
3. Understand that you can't prevent users from running anything that they want on your site, as easily as opening up the dev console and pasting something in.
4. with the understanding of #3, learn how to use #1 and #2 to prevent users running #3 from accessing any data that users give to you (or that you keep about users)

In general, keep user-information out of cookies and URL strings, and keep as much of it within JS-closures, POST-requests and then in the user's session, server-side as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A good resource to read is [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/), which has a massive Wiki-style site full of information about web security. It can be quite heavy going, as there's a lot there, but it's a very good resource to keep in your bookmarks.

Another site that you might find useful is [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/), which aims to help you write PHP code more securely and using best practices. This site is still quite new, but already has some good tips.

My advice for your code: the single best thing you can do to make your code secure is to use a decent PHP framework, instead of writing raw PHP code.

All the good frameworks have libraries that will help you avoid dangerous coding practices. For example, they all have database abstraction layers that no only make database work easier, but also much safer. If you follow the guidelines for the framework you're using, you'll be protecting yourself from a lot of the worst dangers. You still need to know what to look out for, of course, but that will help a lot.

My suggestion for a framework to use would be Symphony or CakePHP, but there are loads of others out there.

Hope that helps.